Problems looping thru a list
The problem I'm having is the following, I have an initial list that I'm trying to divide into multiple lists like the following:
['28/02/2025', '16/03/2025', '16', '14', 'directos', '1.093.026', '29/10/2024', '25/11/2024', '27', '26', 'con', '1.333.784', '28/02/2025', '16/03/2025', '16', '14', 'directos', '1.444.026', '29/10/2024', '25/11/2024', '27', '29', 'con', '1.283.784']

And I want to get something like this so I can work better with the data:
[['28/02/2025', '29/10/2024', '28/02/2025', '29/10/2024'], ['16/03/2025', '25/11/2024', '16/03/2025', '25/11/2024'], ['16', '27', '16', '27'], ['14', '26', '14', '29'], ['directos', 'con', 'directos', 'con'], ['1.093.026', '1.333.784', '1.444.026', '1.283.784']]

What I did is the following:
listota = ['28/02/2025', '16/03/2025', '16', '14', 'directos', '1.093.026', '29/10/2024', '25/11/2024', '27', '26', 'con', '1.333.784', '28/02/2025', '16/03/2025', '16', '14', 'directos', '1.444.026', '29/10/2024', '25/11/2024', '27', '29', 'con', '1.283.784']

p = 0
listas = [[] for _ in range(6)] 
for i, elemento in enumerate(listota):
  if p > 4:
    p = 0
  else:
    listas[p].append(elemento)
    p += 1

When I print(listas) this is the output:
[['28/02/2025', '29/10/2024', '28/02/2025', '29/10/2024'], ['16/03/2025', '25/11/2024', '16/03/2025', '25/11/2024'], ['16', '27', '16', '27'], ['14', '26', '14', '29'], ['directos', 'con', 'directos', 'con'], []]

The last list, the one that should have the prices never appends and i don't really know why. Hope someone notices what im doing wrong.

if comparison was incorrect.  You want to go back to zero after 5 not 4, and always want to do the else: part, so remove the else: line:
listota = ['28/02/2025', '16/03/2025', '16', '14', 'directos', '1.093.026', '29/10/2024', '25/11/2024', '27', '26', 'con', '1.333.784', '28/02/2025', '16/03/2025', '16', '14', 'directos', '1.444.026', '29/10/2024', '25/11/2024', '27', '29', 'con', '1.283.784']

p = 0
listas = [[] for _ in range(6)] 
for i, elemento in enumerate(listota):
    if p > 5:  # 5 not 4.
        p = 0
    # remove else
    listas[p].append(elemento)  # unindent
    p += 1                      # unindent

print(listas)

Output:
[['28/02/2025', '29/10/2024', '28/02/2025', '29/10/2024'], ['16/03/2025', '25/11/2024', '16/03/2025', '25/11/2024'], ['16', '27', '16', '27'], ['14', '26', '14', '29'], ['directos', 'con', 'directos', 'con'], ['1.093.026', '1.333.784', '1.444.026', '1.283.784']]

You can also simplify using modulo arithmetic as:
listota = ['28/02/2025', '16/03/2025', '16', '14', 'directos', '1.093.026', '29/10/2024', '25/11/2024', '27', '26', 'con', '1.333.784', '28/02/2025', '16/03/2025', '16', '14', 'directos', '1.444.026', '29/10/2024', '25/11/2024', '27', '29', 'con', '1.283.784']

listas = [[] for _ in range(6)] 
for i, elemento in enumerate(listota):
    listas[i % 6].append(elemento)

print(listas)


That's great advice, im gonna try using modulo too. Thanks a lot

You can transform the list into a sequence of groups of 6 with itertools.batched, and then zip the groups of rows to produce groups of columns:
from itertools import batched

print(list(map(list, zip(*batched(listota, 6)))))

This outputs:
[['28/02/2025', '29/10/2024', '28/02/2025', '29/10/2024'], ['16/03/2025', '25/11/2024', '16/03/2025', '25/11/2024'], ['16', '27', '16', '27'], ['14', '26', '14', '29'], ['directos', 'con', 'directos', 'con'], ['1.093.026', '1.333.784', '1.444.026', '1.283.784']]

Demo here

Note: batched is a recent addition to Python 3.12.
